# How to remove round corners in Dash to Dock GNOME Extension?

Tags: gnome

I installed the Dash to Dock extension for GNOME and those rounded corners are ugly for me. How do I remove them?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that suits to me but it is not permect. It may be useful for someone. I installed the Arc Theme for gnome and changed the Shell theme to "Arc Dark". In that theme the dock corners are straight, not rounded.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking something like this then simply set opacity to 0%.

[image: dash to dock]

Comment: How does that work? Where do you set it, and on what basic theme?

Comment: This is default theme which comes in Kali 2.0 and you have to set opacity in dash to dock settings!

Answer (score 0):

Use Dconf editor
them follow this path
/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock
there is a option forced straight corner
it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting for this now.  It is called "Force Dock Straight Corners"  it is in the dash to dock settings.